# Unexpected token * during lodash import

Tags: angular, typescript, import, lodash

I have an issue during ts compilation, I had installed lodash

1)npm install --save lodash
2)npm install --save lodash

my class:

```
    import * as lodash from 'lodash';
    class MyDummyClass {
        constructor() {
            console.log('Hello Im a constructor');
        }
        foo() {
            console.log(lodash.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
        }
    }
    const dummyClass = new MyDummyClass();
    dummyClass.foo();
```

I run that using :

```
npx ts-node my-dummy-class.ts
```

my error is:
    Unexpected token *

any idea?

Comment: Can you share full code, e.g. app.module? Did you notice something when you run npm i lodash --save ?

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the lodash NPM by using require:

`import lodash = require('lodash');`

Comment: If I do that I have this error:
Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules consider using import * as ns from  "mod"

Comment: Have you tried installing `types/lodash`? `npm install --save @types/lodash`

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
let _ = require('lodash');
class MyDummyClass {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Hello Im a constructor');
    }
    foo() {
        console.log(_.chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2));
    }
}
const dummyClass = new MyDummyClass();
dummyClass.foo();
```